build and publish npm project with multiple component
I am using vite v:5.2.8 for building my project,
you can see sample in stacklibz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-yjxjye
This is my project structure:
└── ROOT/
    ├── src/
    │   └── utils/
    │       ├── subUtils/
    │       │   └── fixName.ts
    │       ├── log.ts
    │       └── note.ts
    ├── package.json
    ├── tsconfig.json
    └── vite.config.ts

I have two problem:
1 - I expect following structure in my dist folder:
└── ROOT/
    ├── dist/
    │   ├── log.js
    │   ├── log.d.ts
    │   ├── note.js
    │   ├── note.d.ts
    │   └── subUtils/
    │       ├── fixName.js
    │       └── fixName.d.ts

but I have:
└── ROOT/
    ├── dist/
    │   ├── subUtils/
    │   │   └── fixName.d.ts
    │   ├── utils/
    │   │   ├── log.js
    │   │   ├── note.js
    │   │   └── subUtils/
    │   │       └── fixName.js
    │   ├── log.d.ts
    │   └── note.d.ts

2- After I publish my package using npm publish I can't import my component like this:
import myLog from "test-package/log";
import myNote from "test-package/note";
import myFixName from "test-package/subUtils/fixName";

My package is a big utility that contains hundered of files so I don't want to do the following:
in package.json we can have exports like:
  "exports": {
    "./log": "./dist/log.js",
    "./note": "./dist/note.js",
  },

I want to avoid doing it because for every newFile.ts I add to my project , I have to add  "./newFile": "./dist/newFile.js" to exports.
Also there maybe a subfolder like src/utils/subUtils/fixName.ts I need it to simply can import like import myFixName from "test-package/subUtils/fixName";.
I have tried following:
1- adding  "main": "dist/" to package.json
2- npm publish ./dist
3- using rollup input for my entries that you can see in the sample.
So I need to publish dist folder with the following structure that when someone install it, she/he only see these files and can import as I mentioned above.
└── ROOT/
    ├── log.js
    ├── log.d.ts
    ├── note.js
    ├── note.d.ts
    ├── subUtils/
    │   ├── fixName.js
    │   └── fixName.d.ts
    └── package.json


i would suggest to consider named exports so I could do import {myLog, myNote, myFixName} from 'test-package'. Listing tons of imports could be excessive.

I know that I can use this suggest (using one insex.ts and export diffrent module in it and also put `"main": "dist/index.ts" as entry for library. But my need to do it in this way so I am finding for a solution for it, not just cleaning the problem itself. I will apprecite if anyone have any solution for my problem.
